# Whom you vote for "affects" or "affect", if there are multiple politicians elected?

Tags: verb-agreement

I was going to say "Whom you vote for affects the economy" but I was not sure if it should be "affect" or "affects". I think semantically, the subject of "affect" is the whole part before it, but grammatically it seemed that "Whom" looked like the subject, and I meant multiple politicians, not just one politician (imagine, something like the mid-term election), so it could be a plural subject and take "affect".

I asked ChatGPT and it said the following. It seems like it is saying "who" is the plural form of "whom" and is more appropriate if I mean multiple politicians. Is that true?

> The sentence "Whom you vote for affects the economy" is grammatically
> correct, but it can be improved to be more clear when referring to
> multiple politicians being elected.
>
> When talking about multiple politicians, it would be better to use the
> plural form of "who" instead of "whom". Here's an example of how you
> could rephrase the sentence:
>
> "Who you vote for affects the economy, as the collective decisions
> made by elected politicians have an impact on economic policies."
>
> This way, the sentence is clear that it is referring to multiple
> politicians being elected, and the plural form of "who" is used to
> reflect that.

Comment: I would interpret "Whom you vote for affects the economy" as meaning that the way you vote affects the economy, not that the person or people you voted for affect the economy.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216292/who-are-vs-who-is https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263159/can-the-verb-number-be-unknown-in-an-interrogative-sentence-where-the-subject-is and several other questions

Comment: Either stick to the formal usage ("for whom you vote") or the informal one ("who you vote for"); I would advise against trying to combine them ("whom you vote for").

Comment: @nnnnnn: I don't understand the upticks for your comment, which makes no sense at all to me, Feasibly I could apply your interpretation to ***How** you vote [has consequences]*. That's to say irrespective of ***who*** people vote for, the economy could be affected by everyone choosing to vote electronically from home, or sending their votes in by post rather than turning up at the polling station. But that doesn't seem like a credible interpretation with ***Who/Whom...***

Comment: @alphabet: It's just a quick&dirty "rule of thumb" that we tend to avoid ***whom*** today unless it's preceded by a preposition. To a strict grammarian (not me! :) it's a matter of "dative" or "subjective" case (as derived from *Latin* grammar). That's to say, the "pedantic" telephonist should still ask ***Whom** am I speaking **to**?* just the same as ***To whom** am I speaking?*

Comment: @alphabet — *vote for* is a prepositional verb; we would not separate it. *For whom you vote* is incorrect. cf. *care for* in its caregiving sense.

Comment: _Whom_ is not the subject; it's the object of _vote for_, and the preposition can be pied-piped, or not. I wouldn't use _whom_ at all here -- _who you vote for_ is close to a fixed phrase, and perceived as a unit. Diddling with its syntax doesn't help any. As for number agreement, _who(m) you vote for_ is a clause and therefore singular, so it's _affects_ in the present tense.

Comment: @JohnLawler, So, in my original sentence, "who" is correct and "whom" is grammatically incorrect, even though it is the object of "vote for"?

Comment: That's not what I said. I was commenting on the idea that _whom_ was the subject of the sentence. It's not. And I said I wouldn't use it, but not because it's ungrammatical. It **is** grammatical, if rather stiff and formalistic in manner. Whether it's "correct" to its context I couldn't say; I wasn't there. Please don't put words in my mouth.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Here in Australia the expression "the way you vote" usually refers to your choice of whom to vote for. In most (Australian) contexts "how did you vote?" is asking which party you voted for (although many people consider that to be private), not whether you voted by mail or in person. So my original comment meant that I would interpret "Whom you vote for affects the economy" as meaning that your voting decisions have economic consequences.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I doubt any grammarians have explicitly codified this usage into a "syntactic rule". But personally I would *always* treat "bare" ***whom*** as singular when it's the *subject* in a sentence like OP's example, even if there's no doubt that *logically* it could (or even *must*) reference multiple people (or other "elected entities").

But I'd definitely switch to the plural verb form with...

> ***Those** whom you vote for **affect** the economy*.

---

It took me a while to find a written instance of the plural verb form being used in the closely-related construction ***who dare win*** when that's *not* preceded by an explicit "determiner" such as ***those, they, few, many, some,...*** But [here's one...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20brave%20and%20who%20dare%20win%22)

> *Fortune favours **the brave and who dare win**; those who lock themselves away in the loo go home empty handed.*

...where I can understand why the writer chose the verb form, ***dare***. But if it had been me I'd have settled for ***dares*** as "less awkward", even though *logically* it's a bit "off".

Note that the standard *singular* "dare" aphorism parses as the assertion *He who dares is he who wins* - where both ***dares*** and ***wins*** are "tensed, finite" verb forms.

But the usage I just cited above can only be parsed as the noun phrase *those who dare **to** win* (where ***dare*** is "tensed" for plural, but ***win*** is an *infinitive*).

Comment: I detest a driveway downvote, so in that spirit, Mr Fingers: "Whom" in OP's example is the object of *for*, not a subject. Secondly, unlike the examples in your discussion, in OP's example *whom* appears in an *interrogative* clause, not a relative one. This interrogative clause is the subject of the larger sentence, and clauses always trigger singular verb agreement in English.

Comment: I assume "in that spirit" means you're explaining why you downvoted my post. John Lawler had already said *Whom is not the subject; it's the object of vote for* about the  same time I wrote this answer, but I didn't really understand how that affected the singular/plural issue, so I ignored it. He also said *who(m) you vote for* "is a clause and therefore singular", but I didn't understand that either. How come preceding ***whom** [you vote for]* by ***those*** suddenly changes it from singular to plural? Does the same apply to ***[He]** Who hesitates is lost*? It's all a mystery to me!

Comment: Ah, so when you get a clause introduced by *who(m)* or another *wh* word right after a noun, chances are that clause is a relative clause. In that kind of case, the relative clause and the noun phrase it follows combine to make a larger noun phrase. Let's take *the cat who likes cream* as an example. Here the word *cat* and the word *who* have the same referent (as you know, *cat* is the antecedent for *who*). We could instead have *The cats who like cream*, where the antecedent for *who* is the plural *cats* and the verb form is correspondingly *like*. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) But in the OP's example, there is no antecedent, and the clause is not a relative clause. The clause *whom you vote for* does not refer to the people you vote for. It refers to the outcome of (or answer to) the question *Who(m) do you vote for?* and the sentence means something like *The answer to the question "who do you vote for?" affects the economy*. It doesn't mean *The people you vote for affect the economy.* The *whom ...* clause is an 'answer oriented interrogative clause'. Compare *Which pencil**s** you use is not important* and * *Which pencil**s** you use are not important*.

Comment: oic. I get it now. Ty for your patience.

Answer (score -1):

> I asked ChatGPT

A mistake… Such programs are still in their infancy

> It seems like it is saying "who" is the plural form of "whom"

I don’t read it like that – who and whom are pronouns and can refer to a single person or many people.

The man who is talking is a policeman.

The men who are talking are policemen.

"Whom you vote for affects the economy" = The person for whom you vote **affects** the economy.

"Whom you vote for affect the economy" = The person**s** for whom you vote **affect** the economy.

Comment: Shouldn't that last sentence be "Whom you vote for affect the economy"?

Comment: The subject of your latter examples is the interrogative clause "whom you vote for". Interrogative clause subjects  take singular verb agreement in English.